# Is there a way to find out how long a phone call lasted in Cordova

Tags: iphone, cordova

We have a requirement to log how long a phone call lasted.
We are using a cordova plugin called cordova-phone-call
https://github.com/lakshmansha/cordova-plugin-phone-call/
It works well however does not have any callbacks to handle when the call ended thus to find out how long  a phone call lasted.

This one looks promising, although for Android only

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-call-log2

Any help will be appreciated.